# Is there a way to define new literal in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, literals

For example, [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals) is a list of defined ruby literals. Does ruby give us a way to define new "custom" one?

[Updated]
Purpose is to simplify a process of object instantiation. For example if I want to create object based on some dynamic language i'd like to have something like this:

```
obj = @|
  rule1 = "..."
  rule2 = "..."

  value1 = "..."
  value2 = "..."
|
```

instead of

```
hash = {rule1: "...", rule2: "...", value1: "...", value2: "..."}
obj = MyObj.new(hash)
```

Comment: Why would you ever need to do this? Please provide a practical example of a problem you actually face.

Comment: Adding new lexical constructs isn't really a question of necessity, but of convenience. Even though it may be discouraged, people still end up patching core classes regardless. Custom literals being baked into the language would help standardize this practice and make it more comprehensible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. There is no way to change the syntax of Ruby in a Ruby program.

If you want to define a new literal, you have to propose it on the Ruby bugtracker, convince matz that it is a good idea, then convince the developers of YARV, JRuby, Rubinius, IronRuby, MRuby, MagLev, Topaz, Cardinal, tinyrb, MacRuby, RubyMotion, BlueRuby, Opal, XRuby, Ruby.NET, Alumina, SmallRuby, or whatever implementation you care about to implement it, then wait for the community to update to newer versions of the implementations.

Comment: I would add that instead of literals, one should subclass and create their own custom implementation of whatever they needed done. Surely, with the literals available, one should be able to achieve the functionality they need.

Answer (score 5):

> i'd like to have something like this:
>
> ```
> obj = @|
>   rule1 = "..."
>   rule2 = "..."
>
>   value1 = "..."
>   value2 = "..."
> |
> ```

That’s not possible, but you can build something quite similar:

```
obj = MyObj.build {
  rule1 'foo'
  rule2 'bar'

  value1 'baz'
  value2 'qux'
}

obj #=> #<MyObj:0x007fcd7d01ee90 @rule1="foo", @rule2="bar", @value1="baz", @value2="qux">
```

Implementation:

```
class Builder
  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end

  def method_missing(name, value)
    @obj.public_send("#{name}=", value)
  end
end

class MyObj
  attr_accessor :rule1, :rule2, :value1, :value2

  def self.build(&block)
    new.tap { |obj| Builder.new(obj).instance_eval(&block) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in Ruby, you can't. But if you mean in C, you can.