# Is there a way, in ruby, to get and set a specific instance variable just as in built-in types?

Tags: ruby

In ruby, like in any other languages we can get and set built-in types like so

```rb
var1 = 12
if var1 > 10
  var1 = 90
end
```

Now let's say that I am a silly dumby foolish person who wants to deals (for example) with unsigned integers only and create the following class

```rb
class UInteger
  attr_accessor :value
  ...
end
```

is there a way to mimic the built-in variables getter and setter to avoid accessing the `value` by calling

```rb
uint.value
```

or

```rb
uint.value = ...
```

all the time and replace it with just

```rb
uint
```

or

```rb
uint = ...
```

?

Comment: Ruby doesn't have user-defined primitives, but it does allow for a lot of flexibility. What would the goal be with `UInteger`? How would that differ from a regular (`Integer`?) value?

Comment: It would not differ. This was just for the sake of having a simple example. In facts, I would have been pleased to be able to do it with any class (even with complex ones having many instance variables by selecting a "special" one).

Comment: You might be setting expectations on, for example, strongly typed languages where the "type" of the value is bound to the variable, like in this case `uint`. This is not the case in Ruby, the variable is just a "handle" to an object of some kind, and that object has an associated `Class`. As such there is no assignment operator like you'd have in C++, so there's no way to intercept `uint = x` and do anything meaningful, that just swaps out the reference for something with the original object, if any, having no idea it's been cut from that reference.

Comment: If you're setting bounds on numbers, it's usually the job of anyone who cares to vet those, as in the argument must respond to `negative?` as `false`. This is just how "Duck Typing" is usually done. That being said, you could subclass `Integer` to something that will only wrap non-negative values, but that's often a heavy-handed way to do things, and it's unreliable at best since there's so many ways to accidentally circumvent that.

Answer (score 1):

> we can get and set built-in types like so [...]

Yes, but that's in no way limited to build-in "types". You can have the very same code with instances from a custom class. You just have to provide a meaningful `>` method, e.g.: (for demonstration purposes, the class doesn't do anything useful)

```
class UInteger
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value.to_i
  end

  def >(other)
    @value > other.to_i
  end

  def to_i
    @value
  end
end
```

The code structure remains identical otherwise:

```
var1 = UInteger.new(12)
if var1 > UInteger.new(10)
  var1 = UInteger.new(90)
end

var1 #=> #<UInteger:0x00007f898992ebf8 @value=90>
```

You could add a global method `UInteger()` to create new instances more easily (like [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/BigDecimal.html) does) and maybe a custom `inspect` method that resembles its syntax for a less technical output:

```
class UInteger
  # ...

  def inspect
    "UInteger(#{@value})"
  end
end

def UInteger(value) = UInteger.new(value)
```

With the above changes, the code becomes: (these changes are purely cosmetic, it's still instances of `UInteger` just like before)

```
var1 = UInteger(12)
if var1 > UInteger(10)
  var1 = UInteger(90)
end

var1 #=> UInteger(90)
```

Of course, a `UInteger` instance is *not* an actual integer. If you need an integer value, you have to convert it, e.g.:

```
var1 = UInteger(90)

var1.to_i #=> 90
```

Which is no different than converting an instance from a built-in class like string:

```
var1 = "90"

var1.to_i #=> 90
```

Comment: Oh! Almost what I want. Thank you for pointing all of that out.
Since you did not mention it, I suppose there is no way to retrieve the `var1.value` directly with `var1`? A bit like `inspect` does it but without converting it to `String`: if `@value` is an `Integer` then return an `Integer`, if it is an `Array` then return an `Array`, etc.

Comment: @aHzuPFd `var1` is a variable that returns the object you assigned to it. However, can you show some code that reflects your _actual_ problem more closely? The unsigned integer example seems to be rather contrived.

Comment: @aHzuPFd: I know exactly two languages that allow overloading of literals, and those two languages combined have exactly 1 user. So, clearly, overloading of literals does not seem to be a requirement to solve over 99.99999% of all programming problems. This can mean one of two things: either your problem is so incredibly unusual that nobody has ever encountered it in the entire history of computing … or the problem you have doesn't actually require literal overloading to solve. But since we don't know what that problem is, there's not much we can do to help you other than say: it's impossible

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can't change Ruby literals, you can't call `uint` and return instance of `Integer` instead of `UInteger`

Probably [decorator](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator/ruby/example) of integer is something you might need

```rb
class UInteger
  attr_accessor :value

  def initialize(value)
    raise ArgumentError unless value.is_a?(Integer)
    @value = value
  end

  def to_s
    @value.to_s
  end

  def inspect
    @value.inspect
  end


  private

  def respond_to_missing?(name, include_private = false)
    @value.respond_to?(name, include_private)
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    @value.send(method, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

or using [delegate](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) and [delegate_missing_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate_missing_to) methods of Active Support library

```rb
require 'active_support/core_ext/module/delegation'

class UInteger
  attr_accessor :value

  delegate_missing_to :@value
  delegate :to_s, :inspect, to: :@value

  def initialize(value)
    raise ArgumentError unless value.is_a?(Integer)
    @value = value
  end
end
```

And after that you can add to this `UInteger` some specific methods, currently it is dummy and just duplicates integer functionality

Example of usage

```rb
uint10 = UInteger.new(10) # => 10
uint20 = UInteger.new(20) # => 20

uint10.class # => UInteger

uint10 + uint20 # => 30
uint10 + 20 # => 30
uint10 > uint20 # => false
uint10 > 20 # => false
# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

My sense is you're asking if you can create a custom literal in Ruby, since this is the way literals (strings, integers, booleans, etc.) behave in Ruby. **The answer is [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478395/is-there-a-way-to-define-new-literal-in-ruby).**

This seems intentional to the `Object` class, of which your `UInteger` class will automatically inherit from. Since you can override any method on the [Object class](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html), allowing you to override the calling of the object, itself, could create tons of problems. Let's say I do this:

```
class UInteger
  attr_accessor :value, :timestamp
end

uint = UInteger.new
uint.value = 5
```

If I could override `uint` to be `uint.value`, then I wouldn't be able to call `uint.timestamp`:

```
uint 
#=> 5

uint.class
#=> Integer

uint.timestamp
#=> NoMethodError
```

If I could override `uint =` to be `uint.value =` , then I would always overwrite `uint` into an Integer.

```
uint = UInteger.new
#=> true

uint.class
#=> UInteger

uint = 5
#=> true

uint
#=> 5

uint.class
#=> Integer
```